# SQL Server - Select from child-parent-child and return multiple results-set

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, relational-database, azure-sql-database

I am using SQL Server 12/Azure and have 3 tables (T1, T2, T3) where T1 has 1-many with T2 and T3, I want to select from T2 and return the information of T1 records and their associated T3 records.
To give a simplified example, T1 is "Customer", T1 is "Orders", T3 is "CustomerAddresses", so a customer can have many orders and multiple addresses. Now I want to query the orders and include the customers information and addresses, to make things a little bit complicated, the query for orders could include matching on the customer addresses, e.g. get the orders for these addresses.

```
Customer Table                   
----------------------          
Id, Name,...                    
----------------------          

Orders Table                            
------------------------------          
OrderId, CustomerKey, Date,...          
------------------------------          

CustomerAddresses
-----------------------------------------------
AutoNumber, CustomerKey, Street, ZipCode,...
-----------------------------------------------
```

I am having trouble writing the best way (optimized) to return all the results in one transaction and dynamically generate the sql statements, this is how I think the results should come back:

Orders (T2) and customer information (T1) are returned in one result-set/table and CustomerAddresses (T2) are returned in another result-set/table. I am using ADO.NET to generate and execute the queries and use System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader to loop on the returned results.

Example of how the results could come back:

```
Order-Customer Table
-------------------------------
Order.OrderId, Customer.Id, Customer.Name, Order.Date,....
-------------------------------

CustomerAddresses
-------------------------------
AutoNumber, CustomerKey, Street
-------------------------------
```

This is an example of a query that I currently generate:

```
SELECT [Order].[OrderId], [Order].[Date], [Customer].[Id], [Customer].[Name] 
FROM Order 
INNER JOIN [Customer] on [Order].[CustomerKey] = [Customer].[Id] 
WHERE ([Order].[Date] > '2015-06-28')
```

Questions:
1. How do I extend the above query to also allow returning the CustomerAddresses in a separate result-set/table?
To enable matching on the CustomerAddresses I should be able to do a join with the Customer table and include whatever columns I need to match in the WHERE statement.

2. Is there a better, simpler and more optimized way to achieve what I want?

-------- UPDATE ---------------
To clarify more about how I use the returned data in my app:

1. I am using ADO.NET, SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataReader to parse the results. (I don't want to use Entity Framework or any other high-level DB Framework here)
2. My model object is a collection of T2 (Orders) which contains T1 (Customer information) and T3 (CustomerAddresses)

**OrderClass:** 
OrderId, OrderDate, CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerAddresses[],...

**CustomerAddresses Class:** 
Street, ZipCode, ....

I found out that people usually return all the results within a single select statement in one table which returns a redundant data. What I prefer is to return the tables as is (T1, T2 and T3) that only contains the relevant information then I can process it in my app to create the model.

Another solution is to insert the IDs from the select statement into a Temp table then return the results in multiple select statements:

```
Select T1.* From T1 where  Id in (
        select Temp.T1Id from Temp )
Select T2.* From T2 where  Id in (
        select Temp.T2Id from Temp )
Select T3.* From T3 where  Id in (
        select Temp.T3Id from Temp )
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure why you would want 2 inter-related results sets   returned from your database separated in a single transaction? I can only imagine your intention is to reuse all the customer addresses at a later point? However, It would probably be more efficient to fetch a single result set already filtered according to your requirements, then logically separate the set into your required entity model at runtime.

Comment: @Geewers if there is a better way that you can explain to me as an answer that would be great, basically I will be using all these information and compose them as multiple results -domain objects- in my app.

Comment: Sure @zaidsafadi, my first comment is about utilising an existing concept i.e. using a factory pattern in a model layer to build business entities for use by domain objects further up the technology stack. To provide more detail I would need to know a little bit more about your specific situation. For example, are you using ADO.NET Entity Framework DBContexts or ADO.NET SQLConnection and related objects?

Comment: @Geewers please find my update which I hope shed some more light into what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: see my complete answer below. All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first off... It will be easier for you and recommended to create a Stored Procedure with your SQL logic, for example 
    '[dbo].[GetOrderDetails]'.

**The reason is to prevent falling victim to SQL injection and to prevent recompiling and re-distributing your assembly incase your query is updated.**

Here is some interpreted pseudo code to guide you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderDetails] 
(
    @OrderDate DateTime,
    @AddressFilter VARCHAR(128)
)

AS

BEGIN

    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderDetails') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #OrderDetails

    SELECT orders.[*ListYourOrdersColumnsHere*], customer.[*ListYourCustomerColumnsHere*], addresses.[*ListYourAddressColumnsHere*]
    INTO #OrderDetails
    FROM [Order] orders
        INNER JOIN [Customer] customer on orders.[CustomerKey] = customer.[Id] 
        LEFT JOIN [CustomerAddresses] addresses ON addresses.[CustomerKey] = customer.[CustomerKey]
        -- Or inner join if you need orders just with CustomerAddresses
        --INNER JOIN [CustomerAddresses] addresses ON addresses.[CustomerKey] = customer.[CustomerKey]
    WHERE orders.[Date] > @OrderDate
    AND addresses.StreetName LIKE '%' + @AddressFilter + '%'

    -- Orders
    SELECT [*ListYourOrdersColumnsHere*]
    FROM #OrderDetails
    GROUP BY [*ListYourOrdersColumnsHere*]

    -- Customers
    SELECT [*ListYourCustomerColumnsHere*]
    FROM #OrderDetails
    GROUP BY [*ListYourCustomerColumnsHere*]

    -- Addresses
    SELECT [*ListYourAddressColumnsHere*]
    FROM #OrderDetails
    GROUP BY [*ListYourAddressColumnsHere*]

    DROP TABLE #OrderDetails
END
```

Then moving away from the interpreted environment to your managed (compiled) code , you will need to look at :

> SqlDataReader:NextResult()

This method advances the data reader to the next result set as seen below in the next block of pseudo code.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("*YourAzureDbConnectionString*");
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader myReader;

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
myCommand.CommandText = "[dbo].[OrderDetails]";
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrderDate", DateTime.Now);
myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AddressFilter", "Some or other address filter"));

int resultSetCount = 0;

try
{
    myConnection.Open();
    myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    do
    {
        resultSetCount++;
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            switch (resultSetCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    // Populate Order information from 1st resultset
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Populate Customer customer information from 2nd resultset
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Populate CustomerAddress information from 3rd resultset
                    break;
            }                        
        }
    }
    while (myReader.NextResult());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // handle exception logic
}
finally
{
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Finally, this can also be done using SqlDataAdapter which will return your Stored Procedure out put as 3 separate DataTables. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) is a link to the documentation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Geewers for this solution. Actually the .NET part is almost exactly the same as what I have now :). As for the SQL solution, I tried it and it definitely returns the data the way I want it, which is great! Do you know if this method is more efficient than only inserting the primary keys into the temp table/table value param then selecting the records from the original table? (I am thinking your solution is better as the number of rows in the temp table much less than the original table for the individual select statements). Definitely using a Stored Procedure too ;)

Comment: @zaidsafadi, filtering on indexed columns are always the best approach

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question and is a common issue that is apparently not well addressed elsewhere.  The issue, as you allude to, is that since there can be many orders and addresses for each customer, the number of results in a single query can be large. For example,

```
select * from customer
left outer join order 
on (order.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
left outer join customer_orders co 
on (co.customer_id = customer.customer_id)
```

will generate the information you need but will return many results. For example if there are n orders per customer and m addresses per customer there will be mxn results.

So the approach you also allude to is a good approach.  What you are saying is get the customer_ids from the first query and the use those ids to "generate" the order query and the address query.

Essentially what you need to to is to issue queries like:

```
select * from customer
where ....
```

to retrieve the customer information. Then

```
select * from order 
where customer_id in [The customer_ids found in the above query]
```

and

```
select * from customer_address 
where customer_id in [The customer_ids found in the above query]
```

You can use a temp table as you suggests but table valued parameters is going to be more efficient.  Since you are using SQL Server 12 you can use table valued parameters. See the following link for more information about this: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

All these queries should be done in one transaction and you will need to pay attention to transaction isolation levels, which further complicates the issue.

Comment: I am not a db savvy so I thought my issue in the beginning is common and has a straightforward solution, obviously there are real challenges when querying from multiple tables. Thank you for mentioning the table values parameters, I'll definitely take this into account.